# Expression engine core version limitations

Tags: file-uploads, login, security, registration

I'm new to EE and I'm trying to do some securitiy testing on EE.
Is it possible to make user login/registration and fileupload with exression engine core  version? I tried using third party module freemember module but no luck because EE core version doesn't have members module :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've answered the question yourself. The member module is the only way to allow users to login to an ExpressionEngine site that I'm aware of. There are many third-party add-ons that extend the member modules functionality, like Freemember, but none that replace it.

I would say you should buy a license for testing, but unfortunately, a full license of ExpressionEngine is non-returnable.